# Oracle SQL to generate interleaved SQL results

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi i am looking for a way to write a SQL statement which will come out with the following results :-

Lets say we have Dept & Emp ID i would like to generate like records from Dept 3 for the first two rows then followed by Dept 2 with one row then continue Dept 3 and so on :

```
DEPT         EMPID
-----        ------
3              1
3              2
2              3
3              7
3              8
2              9
```

Thank You.

Comment: Your description is vage. Please clarify.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What commands the order of the employees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this

```
SELECT 
  DEPT,
  EMPID
FROM (
      SELECT 
        *,
        ceil((row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY dept ORDER BY EMPID ))/ 2::numeric(5,2)) AS multiple_row_dept,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY dept ORDER BY EMPID ) AS single_row_dept
      FROM 
        test_data2
  ) sub_query 
ORDER BY 
  CASE 
    WHEN DEPT = 2 THEN single_row_dept
    ELSE multiple_row_dept 
  END,
  DEPT DESC,
  EMPID
```

`single_row_dept` specifics which dept should appear only once, in this case its `DEPT 2` followed by multiple other departments

Comment: Thanks !! but i just opted to accomplish this by using application programming language as well ... thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 0):

First order a table by empid in a subquery, 
then calculate a remainder of rowids divided by 3, 
then depending on a result of calculation, return 2 or 3, using `case` expression, 
like this

```
SELECT 
   CASE REMAINDER( rownum, 3 )
     WHEN 0 THEN 2
            ELSE 3
   END As DeptId,
   empid
FROM (
  SELECT empid
  FROM table1
  ORDER BY empid
)
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/bd1bb/3

Comment: Seems thay you simply hardcoded `DeptId`. I guess that the OP meant that every `EmpId` belongs to specific `DeptId` and we just need to output it in that strange manner.

Answer (score 0):

The following code has some limitations:

1) There are only 2 DepId's in the source table

2) Ratio between records having different DepId is exactly 2:1

3) Ordering in one place of the query should be changed depending whether DeptId having more records is naturally greater then the other or not

```
with t as (
select 3 dept_id, 1 emp_id from dual
union all
select 3, 2 from dual
union all
select 3, 7 from dual
union all
select 3, 8 from dual
union all
select 2, 3 from dual
union all
select 2, 9 from dual)

select dept_id, emp_id
  from (select dept_id,
               emp_id,
               dense_rank() over(partition by dept_id order by in_num + mod(in_num, out_num)) ord
          from (select dept_id,
                       emp_id,
                       row_number() over(partition by dept_id order by emp_id) in_num,
/*in the following ORDER BY change to DESC or ASC depending on which dept_id has more records*/
                       dense_rank() over(order by dept_id) out_num
                  from t))
 order by ord, dept_id desc;

   DEPT_ID     EMP_ID
---------- ----------
         3          1
         3          2
         2          3
         3          8
         3          7
         2          9
```